# No Internal Storage in One Touch 8020A

Tags: internal-storage

http://es.tinypic.com/r/2vx3zwn/9

I have only 2 apps and I can not download anything, its a One Touch 8020A.

I have nothing in the internal space, onlynin the SD Card and I am not able to download anything.

Any ideas or solutions?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the One Touch before the phone I have now. It am sad to say that thr phome itself causes the problem. I could barely install an app. Every app would install on internal storage. 
**You have to try install a app on internal and than move to your SD card**

Comment: I do it, no space anyways

Comment: I am not sure, but with my One Touch this problem was never solved, hope you will solve it.

Comment: RIP, I got it as a kinda B Day gift so I couldnt research